# Compare lastwritetime of file to todays date

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to compare the date of a file to today's date but I'm always failing, even if the file is dated today.

My Code:

```
      var dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(line);
      var filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(line);
      var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, filename, System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

      if (files.Length > 0)
      {
        var qry = from x in files
                  where System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(x) == DateTime.Now
                  select x;
        if(!qry.Any())
        {
          Console.WriteLine("boom");
        }
```

I suspect it has to to with the time on it. If so, how do I compare the GetLastWriteTime to today's date?

Thank you!

Comment: _DateTime.Today_ but also the GetLastWriteTime has the time part so you need to clip it using the Date property

Comment: `where System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(x).Date == DateTime.Now.Date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ignore the Time part of a DateTime variable and the GetLastWriteTime otherwise is practically impossible that you get any hit from that code.

```
var qry = from x in files
          where System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(x).Date == DateTime.Today
          select x;
```